# How to properly start and stop shell script in linux, busybox?

Tags: linux, shell-script, busybox

I am trying to write a small shell script that would send some commands to my tv set from my set top box that has busybox on it. The problem is that it generates huge amount of zombie processes, and when I try to killall, I kill also some audio processes, that should not be killed...

Here are my scripts:

tvstart.sh

```
 #!/bin/sh
 echo "ka 1 01" > /dev/ttyUSB0
 read -t 5 response < /dev/ttyUSB0
 echo "xb 1 70" > /dev/ttyUSB0
 read -t 2 response < /dev/ttyUSB0
 echo "kf 1 32" > /dev/ttyUSB0
 read -t 2 response < /dev/ttyUSB0
 echo "km 1 01" > /dev/ttyUSB0
 #killall sh
```

tvstop.sh

```
 #!/bin/sh
 echo "ka 1 00" > /dev/ttyUSB0
 #killall sh
```

And I call them like this(part of the script):

```
case "$1" in
  led-on)
    echo 3 > /sys/class/leds/mag-front-led/mode
    nohup sh /home/default/tvstop.sh &
  ;;
  led-off)
    echo 2 > /sys/class/leds/mag-front-led/mode
    nohup sh /home/default/tvstart.sh &
  ;;
```

So, how do I terminate them properly?
this is how zombies looks like:

```
 3637 root            Z   [sh]
 3660 root            Z   [sh]
 3696 root            Z   [sh]
 3719 root            Z   [sh]
 3751 root            Z   [sh]
 3766 root            Z   [sh]
 3798 root            Z   [sh]
 3829 root            Z   [sh]
 3913 root            Z   [sh]
 3984 root            Z   [sh]
 4489 root       6960 S   sshd: root@pts/0
 4533 root       2704 S   -sh
10478 root            Z   [sh]
10516 root            Z   [sh]
10574 root            Z   [sh]
10597 root            Z   [sh]
10630 root            Z   [sh]
10737 root            Z   [sh]
11072 root            Z   [sh]
11103 root            Z   [sh]
11413 root            Z   [sh]
11436 root            Z   [sh]
11457 root            DW  [STVID.InjecterT]
11458 root            SW  [STVID[0].MPEG2P]
11459 root            DW  [tfm_89287480]
11460 root            SW  [STVID[0].Produc]
11461 root            SW  [STVID[0].Displa]
11462 root            SW  [STVID[0].ErrorR]
11477 root            Z   [sh]
11500 root            Z   [sh]
11525 root            Z   [sh]
11548 root            Z   [sh]
11581 root            Z   [sh]
11605 root            Z   [sh]
11638 root            Z   [sh]
11661 root            Z   [sh]
11688 root            Z   [sh]
19185 root       2704 R   ps
```

Comment: There are `ps` invocation arguments and other programs like `top` that may hint the arguments list of `sh` zombies? Have you identified which program or script all those `sh` are executing?

Comment: Not sure yours, my `busybox ps -Alf` hints an ad hoc `sleep 6` for instance.

Comment: I wouldn't be looking for a way to kill those zombies but for the script/process that generate them and fix it.

Comment: So, is there a way to kill a nohup process? if I try to kill -9 11413 it does not terminate?

Comment: Euhm maybe SIGCHLD but anyway you first try finding a bug in the scripts. You might not be using /dev/ttyUSB0 as you should.

Comment: /dev/ttyUSB0 is a simple rs232 adapter...so it should be read and written...

Comment: You can't kill a zombie because it's already dead. There's nothing left to kill. Zombies can only be reaped. The only thing that's left for a zombie is the entry in the process table, there's no code or memory; reaping removes that entry. A zombie is left because the parent isn't taking care of its dead children. What is the parent of these zombie processes?

Comment: The only way to get rid of zombies is to killall sh, but that is not an option, since it kills some other stuff that are essential...

Comment: Ok, I think I found a solution, it works fine if I add disown at the end...so I call nohup /home/default/tvstart.sh & disown

Comment: Nope, I does not work...the only way not to create a zombie is to call wait in main script...does anyone know a way how not to wait for process to end(dont have to call wait)

Comment: Parent processes **waiting** for child processes and threads is a must go-by for most distributed programming paradigms. Peoples can have their mind mapped like 2 + 2.0002 as to be 4.0002, but many implementations will yield slightly less than 4.0002.